# Allow Countries is losing value overnight

Tags: magento

I have a magento 1.7 instance running on an NGinx server using the file system for cache. 
When I set the Allow Countries field in the admin, it works perfectly. 
24 hours later the setting is no longer being applied to the front end of the site. However, the setting is correct in the admin area.

If I refresh the cache in the admin, it works again in the front end. 
If I delete the files in the var/cache directory, it does not work correctly again.
My var/cache permissions are 755

Anyone have any idea?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer. 
It's due to the Country of Manufacturer sharing a cache key with the getCountriesOptions function in the Checkout.

If you want to fix this, override the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Countryofmanufacture class and change this line

```
$cacheKey = 'DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_SELECT_STORE_' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```

to a different value, e.g.

```
$cacheKey = 'DIRECTORY_COUNTRY_OF_MANUFACTURE_SELECT_STORE_' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```